# Getting html code from another action and manipulate the code throught javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a cshtml view file with the following code:

```
    <ul id="ul1">
        <li id="ul1li1"></li>
        <li id="ul1li2"></li>
        <li id="ul1li3"></li>
    </ul>
```

And an action "x" which returns me html code with which is several divs one after the other.
something like :

```
    <div class="xdiv"></div>
    <div class="xdiv"></div>
    <div class="xdiv"></div>
    <div class="xdiv"></div>
    <div class="xdiv"></div>
```

Id like to use javascript function in order to put the divs I get from the action "X", into the lis in a circular ascending order.
I couldn't find the right solution, and so far my javascript function is something like this :

```
    function fillLis()
    {
        var i = 0;
        divs = @Url.Action("X");
        for(ind in divs){
            div = divs[ind];
            i = i%3 + 1;
            var currentli = document.getElementById('ul1li'+i);
            currentli.innterHTML += div.innerHTML;
        }
    };
```

Because of some bad html coding, I have to do it that way.

Comment: Show us a sample of your expected results in your question

Answer (score 1):

This isn't doing what you think:

```
divs = @Url.Action("X");
```

It's just going to resolve to a string (and a syntax error), such as:

```
divs = /Home/X;
```

What you want to do is make an AJAX request to that action.  (**Note:** Since you're using ASP.NET, I'm assuming that jQuery is an option.)  Something like this:

```
$.get('@Url.Action("X")', function (data) {
    // update your UI
});
```

In that callback function, `data` will contain the response from the server.  Which, in this case, should be the HTML.  At this point it looks like you want to loop over the `div` elements.  So you can probably wrap it in a jQuery object and loop over that.  Something like this:

```
$.get('@Url.Action("X")', function (data) {
    var divs = $('div', data);
    // at this point "divs" is a list of div HTML elements in the response
});
```

Your existing code *should* work on the `divs` array, perhaps with some minor adjustments through debugging.  But essentially that's how you'd get the HTML elements you're looking for from the server in order to use those elements in your client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(@Url.Action("X"), function(xdiv, i) {
    document.getElementById("ul1li"+i).appendChild(xdiv);
});
```

If not then please update your question with more detailed informations about what you're trying to do.

Some quick notes about your code:

```
function fillLis()
    {
        var i = 0;
        divs = @Url.Action("X");
        for(ind in divs){
            div = divs[ind];

            // This will always be equal to 1
            i = i%3 + 1;

            // You say you want to "put the divs [...] into the list", but it seems like you're trying to transfer only the content of your divs
            var currentli = document.getElementById('ul1li'+i);  
            currentli.innterHTML += div.innerHTML;
        }
    };
```